# Improving a tooltip code

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I'm trying to build a hoverable Jquery tooltip.
This tooltip should appear when I hover over some element, and stay
put if I choose to hover over the tooltip itself too.
The tooltip should disappear only if I hover away from the original
element or from the tooltip body.

Based on an example I found, I managed to create this behavior, but
since I'm new to Jquery, I'd be glad to hear your comments about
improving the function.

### The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<script src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<style>
#tooltip{
       position:absolute;
       border:1px solid #333;
       background:#f7f5d1;
       padding:2px 5px;
       color:#333;
       display:none;
       text-align: left;
}

</style>


</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.fn.extend({
       'tooltip': function(text){
                               xOffset = 10;
                               yOffset = 20;

                               var that = this;
                       $(this).mouseover(function(e){
                               this.t = text;
                               $("body").append("<div id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</div>");
                               $("#tooltip")
                                       .css('position', 'absolute')
                                       .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                                       .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
                                       .fadeIn("fast");
                   });
                       $(this).mouseout(function(){
                               that.hide_ff = setTimeout('$("#tooltip").hidetooltip()', 1000);
                               $("#tooltip").hover(function(){
                                       clearTimeout (that.hide_ff);
                               },
                               function(){
                                       $("#tooltip").hidetooltip()
                               });

                               //$("#tooltip").hidetooltip()
                   });
                       $(this).mousemove(function(e){
                               $("#tooltip")
                                       .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                                       .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
                       });
       },

       'hidetooltip': function()
       {
               var that = this;
               $(this).remove();
               if (that.hide_ff)
               {
                       clearTimeout (that.hide_ff);
               }
       }
});

</script>
<a id="fff">ToolTip</a>

<div id="tooltip_share_text" style="display:none">
       <div style="width: 100px;">
       This is a Tooltip.
       <br/>
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert('boo')"> Click Me</a>
       </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#fff").tooltip($('#tooltip_share_text').html());
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Two things bother me most:

1. I needed to extend Jquery with 2 function (tooltip and
   hidetooltip), i would like to achieve the same behavior with only one
   extension but I didn't succeed in accomplishing this.
2. The use I made of "that.hide_ff" just doesn't seem right. Once
   again, I think this variable should belong to a "tooltip" object, but
   if I am not mistaken it is attached to the Jquery object itself.

In addition, I would be happy to hear any other improvements...

Thanks in advance,
Gordi

Answer (score 2):

There is a [tooltip plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) for JQuery.  If you'd rather roll your own, I'm sure you can get ideas by looking at what they have done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're still interested in this... it's been almost a year o.O

But I modified your code a little:

- I got rid of the hidetooltip (the extra extension)
- Using the that.hide_ff is fine, so I didn't change it
- The tooltip pops up at the end of the link and doesn't move with the mouse - it looks cleaner I think.
- Switched the xOffset and yOffset
- Commented out the original mousemove code so you can change it back if you don't like it.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
 'tooltip': function(text){
  xOffset = 10;
  yOffset = 20;

  var that = this;
  $(this).mouseover(function(e){
   this.t = text;
   $("body").append(""+ this.t +"");
   $("#tooltip")
    .css('position', 'absolute')
    .css("top",(this.offsetTop + yOffset) + "px") /* .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px") */
    .css("left",(this.offsetLeft + this.offsetWidth) + "px") /* .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px") */
    .fadeIn("fast");
  });
  $(this).mouseout(function(){
   that.hide_ff = setTimeout('$("#tooltip").remove()', 500);
   $("#tooltip").hover(function(){
    clearTimeout (that.hide_ff);
    },
    function(){
     $("#tooltip").remove();
    }
   );
  });
/*
  $(this).mousemove(function(e){
   $("#tooltip")
    .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
    .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
  });
*/
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) has met all of my tooltip needs: